# How to pass MULTIPLE values for an argument in R using bash

Tags: r, parameter-passing

I'm trying to pass arguments in a R script using bash. As an example, I have the following function:

```
#!/home/rafael/Desktop/Testing Bash ScriptR.R
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

a <- as.numeric(args[1])
b <- as.numeric(args[2])
c <- as.numeric(args[3])


myfunc <- function(a,b,c){
  result <- (a^b) / c
  return(result)
}
final <- myfunc(a,b,c)

write.table(final, file = "teste.txt")
```

It works pretty well so far with the following command:

```
Rscript --vanilla ScriptR.R 10 4 3
```

But my question is: how can I pass MULTIPLE values for each argument of my R function? Because I have a simulation with more parameters and a few values for each parameter. Do I really need to put ALL the values in the command line and index this values inside R?, like this:

```
a <- as.numeric(args[1:10])
...etc
```

...or is there a away to pass this values for each argument in the bash code?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What about using a file and pass the name in?

Comment: @MartinSeehafer Do you mean use a file with my parameters and its values and load this inside R? This might be a better idea than put all the values in the command line.

Comment: Right, if you use, e.g., a *.csv* file you can access the values from R with ease.

Comment: You can also do comma-separated values. If `Rscript --vanilla ScriptR.R 10,11,12 4 3`, then you can do `as.numeric(strsplit(args[1], ",")[[1]])` to get a vector like `c(10,11,12)`. Possibly related: I've used json as an argument (either literal or in a file), so this could be presented as `[[10,11,12],4,3]`; this can be improved by using named parameters, such as `{"param1":[10,11,12],"param2":4,"param3":[3]}`. (You can use [`jsonlite`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html) or [`rjson`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/index.html) internally.)